# Deleted Answers not Disappearing

Tags: support, deleted-answers

In my question, on the main U&L site: [Check if SSH is Enabled or Disabled in Solaris 11](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44921/check-if-ssh-is-enabled-or-disabled-in-solaris-11), I have deleted my own answer, but it hasn't disappeared. **Why has it not gone?** It has gone red though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deleted items are only soft deleted. You can still see them, we moderators can still see them, but it is not visible to the general public.

Comment: Thank you for that. It just was confusing in the beginning, cuz as I deleted it, I still saw it, and it looked like other people could still see it, but was highlighted red.

Comment: Note that it's not just moderators: users with 10k rep and above see other people's deleted answers too.

Comment: It is a nice feature that not only moderators can see them, but the person who deleted it, too. That way I can safely remove my answers without worrying that I might be able to use what I wrote later on. If there just was no -10 rep penalty, then everything would be perfect... :-/